# SQL Server BETWEEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table which has Year, Month and few numeric columns

```
Year   Month  Total
2011     10    100
2011     11    150
2011     12    100  
2012     01    50
2012     02    200
```

Now, I want to `SELECT` rows between 2011 Nov and 2012 FEB. Note that I want the to Query to use range. Just as if I had a date column in the table..

Comment: If you want to use a range, you have to select a calculated column (like concat(year, month)) and that will be bad for performance. Better to use the (admittedly rather complex) query on the two columns separately, because then it can use indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(Year > @FromYear OR Year = @FromYear AND Month >= @FromMonth)
AND (Year < @ToYear OR Year = @ToYear AND Month <= @ToMonth)
```

Comment: I would like to point out that this is functionally identical to the first query in my answer. You have 6 conditions in there, and 5 conjunctions. My first query given has the exact same 6 conditions and 5 conjunctions, just rearranged a bit.

Comment: And ErikE's version is more legible IMHO. In particular, you don't have to know if AND or OR bind stronger.

Comment: @ErikE My apologies, I should have been more careful when posting my answer. I see that your answer generally uses the same approach, in addition to having some other good suggestions. Please consider revising your query, though, as it does not work in some cases where `@FromDate` and `@ToDate` are in the same year. If you address that issue, then I will delete my answer, since it does not provide much information. This kind of table setup (year and month as separate columns) has tripped me up more than once in the past.

Comment: Nice catch! You are absolutely right about my conditions. I will fix it soon.

Answer (score 7):

Coming up with a way to use BETWEEN with the table as it is will work, but will be worse performance in every case:

- It will at best consume more CPU to do some kind of calculation on the rows instead of working with them as dates.
- It will at the very worst force a table scan on every row in the table, but if your columns have indexes, then with the right query a seek is possible. This could be a HUGE performance difference, because forcing the constraints into a BETWEEN clause will disable using the index.

I suggest the following instead if you have an index on your date columns and care at all about performance:

```
DECLARE
   @FromDate date = '20111101',
   @ToDate date = '20120201';

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable T
WHERE
   (
      T.[Year] > Year(@FromDate)
      OR (    
         T.[Year] = Year(@FromDate)
         AND T.[Month] >= Month(@FromDate)
      )
   ) AND (
      T.[Year] < Year(@ToDate)
      OR (
         T.[Year] = Year(@ToDate)
         AND T.[Month] <= Month(@ToDate)
      )
   );
```

However, it is understandable that you don't want to use such a construction as it is very awkward. So here is a compromise query, that at least uses numeric computation and will use less CPU than date-to-string-conversion computation (though not enough less to make up for the forced scan which is the real performance problem).

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable T
WHERE
   T.[Year] * 100 + T.[Month] BETWEEN 201111 AND 201202;
```

If you have an index on `Year`, you can get a big boost by submitting the query as follows, which has the opportunity to seek:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable T
WHERE
   T.[Year] * 100 + T.[Month] BETWEEN 201111 AND 201202
   AND T.[Year] BETWEEN 2011 AND 2012; -- allows use of an index on [Year]
```

While this breaks your requirement of using a single `BETWEEN` expression, it is not too much more painful and will perform very well with the `Year` index.

You can also change your table. Frankly, using separate numbers for your date parts instead of a single column with a date data type is not good. The reason it isn't good is because of the exact issue you are facing right now--it is very hard to query.

In some data warehousing scenarios where saving bytes matters a lot, I could envision situations where you might store the date as a number (such as `201111`) but that is not recommended. The *best* solution is to change your table to use dates instead of splitting out the numeric value of the month and the year. Simply store the first day of the month, recognizing that it stands in for the entire month.

If changing the way you use these columns is not an option but you can still change your table, then you can add a persisted computed column:

```
ALTER Table dbo.YourTable
   ADD ActualDate AS (DateAdd(year, [Year] - 1900, DateAdd(month, [Month], '18991201')))
   PERSISTED;
```

With this you can just do:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE
   ActualDate BETWEEN '20111101' AND '20120201';
```

The `PERSISTED` keyword means that while you still will get a scan, it won't have to do any calculation on each row since the expression is calculated on each INSERT or UPDATE and stored in the row. But you *can* get a seek if you add an index on this column, which will make it perform very well (though all in all, this is still not as ideal as changing to use an actual date column, because it will take more space and will affect INSERTs and UPDATEs):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_YourTable_ActualDate ON dbo.YourTable (ActualDate);
```

Summary: if you truly can't change the table in any way, then you are going to have to make a compromise in some way. It will not be possible to get the simple syntax you want that will also perform well, when your dates are stored split into separate columns.

Answer (score 1):

Your example table seems to indicate that there's only one record per year and month (if it's really a summary-by-month table).  If that's so, you're likely to accrue very little data in the table even over several decades of activity.  The concatenated expression solution will work and performance (in this case) won't be an issue:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ((Year * 100) + Month) BETWEEN 201111 AND 201202
```

If that's not the case and you really have a large number of records in the table (more than a few thousand records), you have a couple of choices:

1. Change your table to store year and month in the format YYYYMM (either as an integer value or text).  This column can replace your current year and index column or be in addition to them (although this breaks normal form).  Index this column and query against it.
2. Create a separate table with one record per year and month and also the indexable column as described above.  In your query, JOIN this table back to the source table and perform your query against the indexed column in the smaller table.

Comment: I don't think #2 makes sense--why create a separate table!?!? #1 and the query you provided are duplicates of information already provided in other answers.

Comment: Creating a separate table allows storage of the indexable values without having to repeat them across tens of thousands of rows in the data table (if that many rows exist).  It significantly reduces the computational load in maintaining the index values, normalizes the relationship between the index values and the year-month pairs they map too, and can be implemented without any permissions at all on the original table.  It does, however, introduce an additional JOIN, which is why I mentioned the less-normal form first.

Comment: I see what you mean, Larry. It does make sense now that you emphasize the one-to-many relationship.