# Assigning values for [Month] parameter in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure, for which the output is a table with [Year] and [Month] columns along with many other columns. I have also created four parameters as @SYear, @SMonth, @EYear, @EMonth. The distinct of [year] is 2015 and 2016. In the month column I have got few months like 2,3,5,7,8 etc in the year 2015 and 1,2 in the year 2016. Now I want to assign the values from the year and month columns to the parameters. In case of year I was able to assign it as ([Year] Between @SYear and @EYear). But when it comes to month if I assign ([Month] BETWEEN @SMonth AND @EMonth), the problem is practically the 5th month of 2015 is less than 1st month of 2016, but as sql is taking [Month] as integer 5 is greater than 1., so it isn't working. If i select @SYear = 2015, @SMonth = 5, @EYear = 2015, @EMonth = 7 it works.

Please suggest a possible way to assign the month column to the starta nd end month parameters.

BTW @S is start @E is end.

Hope I am clear enough for you guys to understand the problem, please let me know if anyone doesn't understand.

thank you.

Edit:
[image]

Here when I select the start year, start month and end year, end month as parameters I should get the results from the table.

Comment: Please provide your code and expected results. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to find with BETWEEN?  What would the result you expect with "the 5th month of 2015 and the 1st month of 2016"?

Comment: This is why you should stored datetime values as datetime. When you split out month and year as integers in their own columns it becomes a real challenge to wrestle with. If at all possible change the datatypes to datetime and this problem is a non-issue.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the data in between those dates when selected. Like a ssrs report parameters. @Kyle

Comment: @SeanLange I only need the start year, month  and end year and month as parameters, that is the problem. Actually I have to build a ssrs report with the stored proc

Comment: @Devart I will try adding some Images, as i don't to how to write code in this website. I am new to this site.

Comment: Could you create a view and add an extra calculated column creating a datetime column?

Comment: @Horaciux I am kind of new to sql, so correct If I am wrong. datetime column should only be in the format of YYYY/MM/DD right? But my parameters should only be year and month

Comment: Right so if you used the date datatype it would be simple. To be honest you will most likely need to concatenate your parameters after casting them to varchars as a date do you can use date logic. When you start wrestling with dates as strings you are in for a long and painful struggle.

Comment: @SeanLange Can you please help me with the code for that? So that my parameters will be in the format of StartDate = '5/2015' and Enddate = '1/2016', If I understood your comment correctly?

Comment: Ouch.....the real problem is you are storing this as separate columns. You are fighting a poor design. If these columns were dates instead this would be so simple. Can you pass in a date parameter instead of 4 integers? The way you have this currently you will have to cast your parameters as a date but you will also have to concatenate your columns into a date value so you can use date logic on them. Ugh.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes those two are separate columns. I would like to try your approach but my question is can a datetime be in the format of 1/2015, 5/2015, 10/2015 like that? I mean to say as MM/YYYY without  date? Thank you.

Comment: Work with this `SELECT
  DATEFROMPARTS ( [Year], [Month], 1 ) AS NewDate
FROM
  YourTable` 1 is for Day, all integers. This function works on SQL Server 2008 and beyond

Comment: You tagged this with 2008? Is that the version of sql you are using? I would have suggested using DATEFROMPARTS but isn't available until sql2012.

Comment: @SeanLange My mistake, I am sorry. Mine is sql2012.

Comment: @Horaciux It worked but not exactly want i wanted. As others said it wont be a good option to work with date columns as strings, I will try working with your method and see how it helps me for my report.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963982/sql-server-between/13964381

Comment: That worked like a charm! I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, long comment

This is ugly, I Know, if you can't work with DATEFROMPARTS() something like this might work (or cast strings)

```
SELECT *

FROM table1 t

WHERE
DATEADD(mm, t.Month -1, dateadd(yy,t.Year-1900,'19000101'))
BETWEEN
DATEADD(mm, @sMonth -1, dateadd(yy,@sYear-1900,'19000101'))
AND
DATEADD(mm, @eMonth -1, dateadd(yy,@eYear-1900,'19000101'))
```

Comment: It didn't work. It's pulling all the records instead of the specified parameters.

Comment: what happend if you run this `SELECT DATEADD(mm, @eMonth -1, dateadd(yy,@eYear-1900,'19000101')) as endDate`

Comment: I am getting all null values

Comment: `declare @eYear int, @eMonth int;
set @eYear=2015;
set @eMonth=7;
select DATEADD(mm, @eMonth -1, dateadd(yy,@eYear-1900,'19000101'));` It is not null, is a datetime 20150701 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

This replaces my previous answers so that it answers the question fully. This turned out to be one of those things that is a lot harder than it seems it should be. I really thought Answer #2 below (creating a calculated field) would be the sure-thing fallback answer, but turns out you cannot use CAST() with a DATE type in a PERSISTED field, so that added to the complexity.

**THIS IS ANSWER 1, use it if...**

- You need to do this query frequently
- You have lots of data and need an index
- You don't mind changing your table structure

The 'right way' is to add a column that is an actual DATE by adding a field with the actual MONTH/YEAR and a dummy "1st" for the day. Store it as a DATE and then use it for querying. This can be indexed and will be as fast as it gets.

**THIS IS ANSWER 2, use it if...**

- You need to do this query frequently
- You have minimal data and therefore do not need an index
- You don't want to change your table structure

You can create a calculated field on your table using either of the following methods. This way whenever you write a query you can just use the date field and life is simple -- except you will not hit on an index.

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD THE_DATE1 AS CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), THE_YEAR ) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), THE_MONTH) + '-01'

ALTER TABLE table1
ADD THE_DATE2 AS DATEADD(mm, THE_MONTH -1, dateadd(yy,THE_YEAR-1900,'19000101'))

ALTER TABLE table1 -- SQL212+
ADD THE_DATE3 AS DATEFROMPARTS(THE_YEAR, THE_MONTH,  1)
```

**THIS IS ANSWER 3, use it if...**

- You need to do this query frequently
- You have lots of data and do need an index
- You don't mind crazy queries

You can use a crazy WHERE statement to get your data. There are two version below, the second version includes some AND statements that will help SQL SERVER hit on some indexes (because SQL doesn't like having a bunch of OR operators in your WHERE statement).

```
DECLARE @table1 AS TABLE (
         ID INT ,
         THE_YEAR INT ,
         THE_MONTH INT ,
         THE_MONEY INT
        )

INSERT  INTO @table1
VALUES  ( 1, 2015, 5, 20 ),
        ( 2, 2015, 7, 50 ),
        ( 3, 2015, 9, 8 ),
        ( 4, 2015, 10, 60 ),
        ( 5, 2015, 12, 30 ),
        ( 6, 2016, 1, 90 ),
        ( 7, 2016, 2, 120 ),
        ( 8, 2017, 1, 220 ), -- Added for testing
        ( 9, 2017, 2, 320 )  -- Added for testing

DECLARE @START_YEAR INT = 2015;
DECLARE @START_MONTH INT = 7;

DECLARE @STOP_YEAR INT = 2015;
DECLARE @STOP_MONTH INT = 10;

-- QUERY THAT ANSWERS YOUR QUESTION

SELECT  *
FROM    @table1
WHERE   (
            ( @START_YEAR <> @STOP_YEAR AND THE_YEAR  = @START_YEAR AND THE_MONTH >= @START_MONTH )
            OR 
            ( @START_YEAR <> @STOP_YEAR AND THE_YEAR > @START_YEAR AND THE_YEAR < @STOP_YEAR )
            OR 
            ( @START_YEAR <> @STOP_YEAR AND THE_YEAR  = @STOP_YEAR  AND THE_MONTH <= @STOP_MONTH )
            OR 
            -- Handle when Start/Stop year are the same
            ( @START_YEAR  = @STOP_YEAR  AND THE_MONTH >= @START_MONTH AND THE_MONTH <= @STOP_MONTH )
        )
ORDER BY THE_YEAR ,
        THE_MONTH


-- QUERY THAT ANSWERS YOUR QUESTION, with INDEX optimizations
-- because once you have a bunch of data, this may help you hit on an index.
SELECT  *
FROM    @table1
WHERE   THE_YEAR >= @START_YEAR   -- Will hit an INDEX if you have one on THE_YEAR
        AND THE_YEAR <= @STOP_YEAR -- Will hit an INDEX if you have one on THE_YEAR
        AND
        (
                ( @START_YEAR <> @STOP_YEAR AND THE_YEAR  = @START_YEAR AND THE_MONTH >= @START_MONTH )
                OR 
                ( @START_YEAR <> @STOP_YEAR AND THE_YEAR > @START_YEAR AND THE_YEAR < @STOP_YEAR )
                OR 
                ( @START_YEAR <> @STOP_YEAR AND THE_YEAR  = @STOP_YEAR  AND THE_MONTH <= @STOP_MONTH )
                OR 
                -- Handle when Start/Stop year are the same
                ( @START_YEAR  = @STOP_YEAR  AND THE_MONTH >= @START_MONTH AND THE_MONTH <= @STOP_MONTH )
            )
ORDER BY THE_YEAR ,
        THE_MONTH
```

Comment: I will definitely try this and let you know if it works. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: This looks like it will have problems if `@START_YEAR` and `@STOP_YEAR` are the same year; for example, between June 2015 and September 2015. I think it will retrieve data from the entire year.